# I am working on Angular2 project and need to know about routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on an angular 2 project where I am using routing functionality to go from one page to another. Basically routing is appending the next page name in URL for Eg. we are on main page index.html and moving to XYZ page, so URL becomes index.html/XYZ.
I am looking for the solution so that I can move to XYZ page as well as URL will be index.html only. And the same functionality will work on page refreshing as well.
Can anyone suggest how can I achieve that and is it similar to angular-2-local-storage ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using RouterModule and Routes, and in routing.ts I am writing similar code:

`{ path: 'games/football', component: FootBallComponent }`

Now on UI, it shows like 
`localhost:4200/games/football`

is there anyway to show URL as 

`localhost:4200/Games`

Answer (score 2):

you can write an empty path in your routing array to redirect you to any page you want:

```
  const signupRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: XYZ}
  ];
```

Comment: yes, but I want to retain the data with which a User came to that page, so how to handle that situation. For Eg.

Comment: yes, but I want to retain the data with which a User came to that page, so how to handle that situation. For Eg.
User is on index.html and have three records to choose, Toys, Cards and cups. Now when User will click on any particular record (Toys), we can do it by your suggested answer and will be able to go to Toys page and URL will still be index.html but when User will refresh the screen then how will we come to know that before refresh he was on which screen.? 
Please let me know if I was not able to explain you properly.